# html.Button inside a row and column of a dash_table.DataTable

Tags: datatable, plotly-dash

Hi I want to ask if it possible to add a `html.Button` element inside a `dash_table.DataTable` rows?
I want to edit a value in the column of the row by adding a button inside of the cell.
I wonder if is supported by the `dash_table.DataTable`?

Comment: There is a property to edit the cell directly, why do you want to add a button inside the cell to edit it?